# Check which JS module needs to be transpiled with Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Webpack + Babel, but transpiling `node_modules` throws lots of errors, even if I try to exclude specific modules. I think a better approach would be to figure out which modules won't work in older browsers and only transpile those modules. Is there an easy way to do this?

Ideally, I'd be able to compare a file produced by Webpack with a `browserslistrc` file and see which modules would cause the output to not be compatible with the browsers in `browserslistrc`.